# Get the import name of a module

Tags: python

I have the following:

```
import numpy as np
v = np.ndarray([1,2,3,4,5])
```

I'm interested in examining `v` and somehow recovering that it is of type `np.ndarray`.

What doesn't work:

1. `type(v).__name__` gives `ndarray` without the `np`.
2. `type(v).__qualname__` gives `ndarray` without the `np`.
3. `type(v).__module__` gives `numpy` not `np`.

How can I get `np.ndarray` back?

Comment: [`np` is just a local alias in the namespace of your program.](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0221/)

Comment: Just clarify your question. what if `import numpy as np; np2=np; v=np2.ndarray([1,2,3]);` ?

Comment: @Nathan, I would still want `np` then.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One way is to look up the alias used for the module in `globals()`.

```
def name_of(x):
    t = type(x)
    alias = next(
        k
        for k, v in globals().items()
        if hasattr(v, "__name__") and v.__name__ == t.__module__
    )
    return f"{alias}.{t.__name__}"
```

Example usage:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> name_of(np.array([]))
'np.ndarray'
```

Furthermore, since dictionary iteration is insertion-ordered, this will return the alias that was first declared.